# Change number of reducers/mappers in DataStax Enterprise

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, datastax

How can I change the number of mappers/reducers in Hadoop? For some odd reason, mapred.tasttracker.map.tasks.maximum and mapred.tasttracker.reduce.tasks.maximum are not present in the mapred-site.xml. I did manage to find these settings in dse-mapred-default.xml but once the xml is opened, there's a note which indicates that the settings shouldn't be edited in this file and that the properties should be overridden in mapred-site.xml.

I have tried adding the two settings to the mapred-site.xml and restarting Hadoop and i was expecting the numbers to also be updated in dse-mapred-default.xml but with no luck.

Could someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks
Majd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `mapred.tasttracker.map.tasks.maximum`, but `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`. I hope it is only a typo and you used correct names in your config.

On startup DSE creates dse-mapred-default.xml and dse-core-default.xml files and fills them with defaults adapted to your local OS configuration and hardware. This is mostly for Hadoop autotuning feature and for simplifying configuring of security-enabled Hadoop. Then Hadoop loads config files in the following order:

1. Hadoop internal defaults (the defaults you can find in the Hadoop docs)
2. DSE defaults from dse-core-default.xml and dse-mapred-default.xml
3. User files: core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml.

Settings from files loaded later override settings loaded earlier. The final state of configuration is *not* written back to the files with defaults. You should not expect settings from mapred-site.xml to be copied into dse-mapred-default.xml files.

If you're unsure what is the final configuration and whether your settings are properly set - just run a job and look into hadoop log directory and search for files matching pattern job_xxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxx_conf.xml, where x is a digit. You can also view the final config in the jobtracker HTTP console.

Comment: Thanks Piotr. Will check the log to see if the settings have actually been applied. One more thing please. When I do a dump in pig, I get the following messages on the console: attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% INFO 15:55:33,801 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% INFO 15:55:36,860              I'm running a 5 node Hadoop cluster containing 500k items. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe ask another question with full steps to reproduce. BTW: If you find an answer on SO useful, please mark it as accepted.